# How to make a 'variable' method name in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, methods

I'm new to C# programming, have a little bit of background in C/C++. I'm trying to write a problem, like an equalizer almost, just playing with code. Imagine 5 vertical sliders next to each other, and when you move the middle slider up and down, the other sliders react with a specific value, based on a hash function I'll figure out at a later date, at the moment I have simple equations.

However, when I add more sliders, I don't want to go through and add a function for every single slider, so is there a way to 'detect' which slider is moving, and send it through an algorithm to move the the adjacent sliders? Basically, I'd like one function to move the adjacent sliders to any slider I choose to move. Logically, it makes sense, however I don't know how to do it in code.

The function that I've written for a specific slider is below.

```
private void slider3_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        double adjacentSliders = ((slider3.Value) / 4) * 3;
        double adjacentSliders2 = ((slider3.Value) / 2);
        slider2.Value = slider4.Value = adjacentSliders;
        slider1.Value = slider5.Value = adjacentSliders2;
    }
```

I may have not explained it fully, feel free to ask questions!

Comment: You want an array of sliders.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void anySlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
   var thisSlider = sender as Slider;
   ...
}
```

When you need the adjacent sliders, build a List of the sliders in FormLoad. You can then find the index of `thisSlider` and work from there.

Edit: I'm not sure if WPF triggers the events when changing values in code. If it does you may need this to prevent it from going into a loop:

```
private static bool changingSlider = false;

private void anySlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    if (! changingSlider)
    {
        changingSlider = true;      
        var thisSlider = sender as Slider;
        ...
        changingSlider = false;
}
```

Comment: I guess I see what you're trying to... No, I don't get it.  I guess the upvoters do though.

Comment: Yeah.  I still don't get it.  This seems like step one, and there's five other steps after it.  I could probably figure it out, but I know what I'm doing.

Comment: I didn't pretend to post a complete-working-code answer. I rarely do. I think this is the missing piece for the OP.

Comment: How do you code an event for a new slider, when it is added to the collection?  `slider3_ValueChanged` only works for slider 3.

Comment: You only need 1 event-handler. Using `sender` makes it generic. The Form must maintain a List<Slider>, that's most of the work. (But I changed the name :-)

Comment: And that fires when you move any one of the sliders?  Where do you hook it?

Comment: No, anySlider_ValueChanged. Ahh, I seem to forget a re-entrancy protection. Will add a little.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - in WPF you can hook it once to the containing Panel (and then use args.Source instead of sender). But otherwise, you can hook up the 1 handler to all sliders in code or even with the designer. I don't see any problem there.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use C# and Visual Studio for a while, so I can't remember if there is a direct way to use arrays in the window designer, someone should clear that in the comments ;).

But what you probably want is to Instead of declaring slider1, slider2, slider3, ... you should use an array so that you can access slider[0], slider[1], ...

For this you firstly must change the design of the form to use an array and then access this array in your handler.

without array:

```
        private System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar trackBar1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar trackBar2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar trackBar3;

        [...]

        this.trackBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar();
        this.trackBar2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar();
        this.trackBar3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBar1)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBar2)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBar3)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // trackBar1
        // 
        this.trackBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(154, 80);
        this.trackBar1.Name = "trackBar1";
        this.trackBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 45);
        this.trackBar1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // trackBar2
        // 
        this.trackBar2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(154, 132);
        this.trackBar2.Name = "trackBar2";
        this.trackBar2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 45);
        this.trackBar2.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // trackBar3
        // 
        this.trackBar3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(154, 184);
        this.trackBar3.Name = "trackBar3";
        this.trackBar3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 45);
        this.trackBar3.TabIndex = 2;
```

with array:

```
        private System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar[] trackBar = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar[3];

        [...]
        this.SuspendLayout();

        for(int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
            this.trackBar[n] = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBar[n])).BeginInit();

            this.trackBar[n].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(154, 80 + n*52);
            this.trackBar[n].Name = "trackBar[" + n + "]";
            this.trackBar[n].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 45);
            this.trackBar[n].TabIndex = 0;
        }
```

Then you can access all track bars via trackBar[x]. You can change the 3 in the declaration and for loop to a constant you want or to a variable.

Comment: The OP uses WPF, not WinForms. And the array and the designer code are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry. Didn't see the wpf tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it in xaml only. You just need a `FormulaCalculationConverter`. I tried it and it works well.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WpfApplication2="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <sys:Double x:Key="MyValueFour">4.0</sys:Double>
    <sys:Double x:Key="MyValueTwo">2.0</sys:Double>
    <WpfApplication2:FormulaCalculationConverter x:Key="FormulaCalculationConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Slider x:Name="BaseSlider" />
    <Slider>
        <Slider.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FormulaCalculationConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Value" ElementName="BaseSlider" Mode="OneWay"  />
                <Binding Path="." Source="{StaticResource MyValueFour}" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Slider.Value>
    </Slider>
    <Slider >
        <Slider.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FormulaCalculationConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Value" ElementName="BaseSlider" Mode="OneWay"  />
                <Binding Path="." Source="{StaticResource MyValueTwo}" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Slider.Value>
    </Slider>
    <Slider Value="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=BaseSlider}"/>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and I just created a converter like

```
public class FormulaCalculationConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
   // this is incomplete formula converter...
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
       // strictly assume for 1 + 1
       double retVal = 0;
       if (values[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue
           || values[0] == null || values[1] == null)
       {
           return Binding.DoNothing;
       }
       // apply logic to split formula here
       retVal = System.Convert.ToDouble(values[0]) + System.Convert.ToDouble(values[1]);
       return retVal;
   }

   public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

But you need to work on converter for this. Let me know your thoughts.